# Sendgrid Web API Basic install not sending email using Meteor Method

Tags: meteor, sendgrid

I'm using the SendGrid WebAPI for Node.js.

I followed these instructions:
[image: Environmental Variables Set Up]

I have the following code in a method I trigger from the client.

```
// using SendGrid's v3 Node.js Library
// https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
const msg = {
  to: 'test@example.com',
  from: 'test@example.com',
  subject: 'Sending with SendGrid is Fun',
  text: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js',
  html: '<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js</strong>',
};
sgMail.send(msg);
```

When I trigger the method to send, I get an odd error (below) - Not sure why this is happening.  Hoping for some ideas.

Thank you!!

---

ERROR:

```
(node:21240) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
W20190301-07:12:22.267(-8)? (STDERR)     at Object.keys.forEach.key (packages/ejson/ejson.js:594:27)
W20190301-07:12:22.267(-8)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
W20190301-07:12:22.268(-8)? (STDERR)     at Object.EJSON.clone.v [as clone] (packages/ejson/ejson.js:594:18)
W20190301-07:12:22.268(-8)? (STDERR)     at Object.keys.forEach.key (packages/ejson/ejson.js:595:22)
W20190301-07:12:22.268(-8)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
W20190301-07:12:22.268(-8)? (STDERR)     at Object.EJSON.clone.v [as clone] (packages/ejson/ejson.js:594:18)
W20190301-07:12:22.268(-8)? (STDERR)     at Object.keys.forEach.key (packages/ejson/ejson.js:595:22)
W20190301-07:12:22.268(-8)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
W20190301-07:12:22.268(-8)? (STDERR)     at Object.EJSON.clone.v [as clone] (packages/ejson/ejson.js:594:18)
W20190301-07:12:22.268(-8)? (STDERR)     at Object.keys.forEach.key (packages/ejson/ejson.js:595:22)
W20190301-07:12:22.268(-8)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
W20190301-07:12:22.268(-8)? (STDERR)     at Object.EJSON.clone.v [as clone] (packages/ejson/ejson.js:594:18)
W20190301-07:12:22.269(-8)? (STDERR)     at Object.keys.forEach.key (packages/ejson/ejson.js:595:22)
W20190301-07:12:22.269(-8)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
W20190301-07:12:22.269(-8)? (STDERR)     at Object.EJSON.clone.v [as clone] (packages/ejson/ejson.js:594:18)
W20190301-07:12:22.269(-8)? (STDERR)     at Object.keys.forEach.key (packages/ejson/ejson.js:595:22)
W20190301-07:12:22.269(-8)? (STDERR) (node:21240) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 9)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, by putting your API_KEY on the client side, you're showing it, and it should be kept secret.

Create a new file `server/smtp.js`. By putting it in a `server/` directory, Meteor will put it only on the server side, this code will not be visible from the client side:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://username:password@smtp.sendgrid.net:587';
});
```

Add the email package to meteor. On the command line:

`meteor add email`

Create a file `server/methods.js` to add some server side methods:

```
Meteor.methods({
  sendmail(to) {
    // for security reasons, you should validate the 'to' argument
    // but let's forget that for now.
    Email.send({
      from: "me@paulpedrazzi.com",
      to: to
      subject: "Awesome",
      text: "It worked"
    });
  }
});
```

Whenever you want to send an email, on the **client side** call this method and pass it the necessary arguments:

```
Meteor.call('sendmail', ‘elon.musk@tesla.com’, (err, res) => {
  if (err) {
    alert(err);
  } else {
    // success!
  }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I was trying to not use the old meteor mail package.  I played around with the main npm sendgrid library and it works out well without any addional meteor goodness.  Appreciate you taking the time to reply!